# Base UseCase with coroutines kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture, use-case

I want to have a BaseUseCase class by following:

- Must allow to indicate the parameters.
- Must run the work itself in a background thread (that would be the doWork method).
- Must return the value in the main thread.

I want to return a value instead of returning it through a callback because I want the function that calls the usecase to be able to return the value directly once the usecase is finished.

I have the following approach, but I do not know if it is correct. I am using twice the *@withContext*, so I do not konw if it can be improved. Can you help me?

Current code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

abstract class SimpleBaseUseCase<out ResultType, in Params> where ResultType : Any {
    private val backgroundDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
    private val uiDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

protected abstract suspend fun doWork(params: Params): Result<ResultType>

/**
 * @param params input data for the background job
 * @return the type of data indicated in @ResultType generic wrapped in a Result object.
 */
open suspend operator fun invoke(params: Params): Result<ResultType> = withContext(uiDispatcher) {
    withContext(backgroundDispatcher) {
        doWork(params)
    }
}
```

}

And, the caller would be:

```
class CustomHandler { 
    //...

    suspend fun methodThatCallsUseCase: Result<String> {
        return useCase("paramExample")
    }
}
```

Comment: the double `withContext` makes no sense. Which dispatcher do you want to run on? There can be only one. And calling `useCase()` from `methodThatCallsUseCase` like that won't work: The outer function is not `suspend` so it can't call `suspend` functions.

Comment: I added the "suspend" indicator. I just want to execute the doWork() code in a background thread and return the value in the main thread (or the same that was used to call the usecase)

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. The code will work exactly the same without the outer `withContext`. Once you return from that block, the context will return to whatever the caller's context was.

Comment: so, is just about removing the outer `withContext` and I'll get what I want in the correct way?

Comment: Assuming `methodThatCallsUseCase` is already running on `Dispatchers.Main`, yes.

Comment: A suspend function cannot control what dispatcher its caller resumes on. Its caller will resume on whatever dispatcher it was using when it called this suspend function. It's up to the caller to make sure its on the appropriate dispatcher for the non-suspending calls that it makes.